# Using different templates for different nodes in Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I am using Drupal 7. I want to add a template for a group of nodes. For example, If i have three nodes node/3, node/4, and node/5, I want to use a particular template. Is there a way to do that? If it is, How can i do that? Or What is the best alternate method?

Now I am using page.tpl.php template for all the pages except the front page.

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at this:
https://drupal.org/node/1089656

The node--[type|nodeid].tpl.php part may be what you are looking for.

The theme developer module can be a good way to find out the proper template suggestions
https://drupal.org/project/devel_themer

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that.

For example you can place condition on node id in page.tpl.php.

Or you can use different templates for each node like here [Template suggestions for page on specific node id](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/24539/template-suggestions-for-page-on-specific-node-id) and inside this templates you can include **same** template for each group using just include.